# Why does my HP 10 Slate Tablet factory reset every time I turn it on?

Tags: root-access, factory-reset, busybox, kingo

I rooted my HP 10 (4.4.2) with Kingoroot, as I was unable to find anything else capable of doing so. It actually worked fairly well, except that if the tablet gets turned off and turned back on again, it acts like a factoy reset prompting me to enter user info, language, etc. I unrooted with Kingo, rerooted, unrooted with SuperSu, rerooted, unrooted with an App off the Play Store, tried factory resetting through the recovery, wiped the cache, and even drained the battery hoping that may kick something out.

I also downloaded Busybox and ran it and manually moved the busybox file with rootexplorer.

I am assuming that Kingoroot did something to it initially, but rooted or unrooted, the tablet factory reset starts every time. Is there something like a MBR or something that needs to be rewritten or is there a /system file that needs to be recovered?

Hopefully that is enough information to help someone get started to figure out what I did.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too on my old Chinese tablet. What I did was move the `busybox` file to `/system/xbin` using a root explorer and reboot. It worked fine after that.

Comment: I tried the busy box method, the app and manually moving it. The tablet reset on the next boot up like I didn't do anything. This is why I am perplexed, every scenario I've seen posted by someone else involved the busy box fix.

Comment: @Sebix Can you install apps on the tablet? And also what does the storage option in the settings show?